# Is setNumThreads(x) parallelizing my OpenCV code?

Tags: opencv

I really wonder if using OpenCV's `setNumThreads();` really allows my code to run in parallel. I've searched a lot on the internet without finding any answer for my question.

Someone there have any answer for my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect depends greatly on the configuration options you select on cmake configure, see for example [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/693129902d9a5b5d8786a5293551e9e5b40c9e04/CMakeLists.txt#L931), plus the catches of the different [configuration options](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/e59c74e1c7672ad16056f32136a491b1e008e295/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp#L76):

```
/* IMPORTANT: always use the same order of defines
   1. HAVE_TBB         - 3rdparty library, should be explicitly enabled
   2. HAVE_CSTRIPES    - 3rdparty library, should be explicitly enabled
   3. HAVE_OPENMP      - integrated to compiler, should be explicitly enabled
   4. HAVE_GCD         - system wide, used automatically        (APPLE only)
   5. HAVE_CONCURRENCY - part of runtime, used automatically    (Windows only - MSVS 10, MSVS 11)
*/
```

And with those, you can understand [the code itself](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp#L341). All that said, the parallelising engine won't do much if you're running an inherently sequential algorithm, which is practically everything under OpenCV... My guess is that *if* you would have several OpenCV programs running in parallel, you could see a meaningful difference.

Answer (score 0):

Feel the need to build on miguelao's answer: most of OpenCV's functionality is NOT multithreaded. setNumThreads only effects multithreaded functions, such as `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`.

Normally by default, OpenCV will use as many threads as you have cores. So `setNumThreads` won't give you a speed gain.

My main use for it is disabling multithreading, so that I may do my own with coarser granularity.